# How to animate just one UITableView cell/row based on something like description?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

i have description , title in a cell .. some of the title has description some doesnt have . i want to animate ( increase the size ) the row based upon description , if there is no description the cell shouldnt increase the size where as if there is description the cell should increase .  the data of title and description is fetched from sql db .i have created the animation part , i am having trouble in increase the size of cell only for description part .. - (void)tableViewUITableView *)tableView cellForRowIndexNSIndexPath *)indexPath i have defined descriptionlabel which gets value from descriptionArray

```
- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@implementation LOAnimatedCellDemoViewController

#define kCellHeight 50.0

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    selectedIndexes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [selectedIndexes release];
    selectedIndexes = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    return selectedIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tableview Datasource Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tableview Delegate Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

    // Toggle 'selected' state
    BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

    // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
    [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath]; 

    // This is where magic happens...
    [demoTableView beginUpdates];
    [demoTableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If our cell is selected, return double height
    if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        return kCellHeight * 2.0;
    }

    // Cell isn't selected so return single height
    return kCellHeight;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) line i added

`if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath] && ![descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] isEqualToString:@" "])` 
 i gave ***isEqualToString:@" "*** cause in database column for items which has no description i gave ***single space character*** so that it indicates there is no description is available for the item –

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

    // Toggle 'selected' state
    BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

    // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
    [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath]; 

    // This is where magic happens...
    [demoTableView beginUpdates];

    //these two lines were added
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]; 
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];   

    [demoTableView endUpdates];
}
```

And make sure you return proper (big/small) view in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when it's called during the process.

Comment: NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]; 
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

according to the above code how does the cell/row knows if the description is present in the cell or not ? the cell shouldnt increase the height (it should be normal )if there is no description in the cell , it should only increase the height when there is description

Comment: Your cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath will get called and there is where you deal with this. Information on whether description is present in a certain cell or not should be stored outside - in a data model-

Comment: i was able to solve that but i have come up with another problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466797/row-is-not-getting-deselected-in-uitableview-cell-animation

Comment: @orgami: i'll take a look. And please post your solution to this question here so others will have benefit of it (people who would ask similiar question on the future)

Comment: if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath] && ![descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] isEqualToString:@" "])  this is how i was able to solve the problem .. i gave isEqualToString:@" " cause in database for items which has no description i gave it single space character so that it indicates there is no description is available for the item