# row is not getting deselected in UITableview cell animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

```
- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    return selectedIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // Toggle 'selected' state
    BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];
    // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath  
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
    [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];   
    // This is where magic happens...
    [beveragesTableView beginUpdates];
    [beveragesTableView endUpdates];

    [selectedIndexes removeAllObjects];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // If our cell is selected, return double height
    if ([self cellIsSelected:indexPath] && ![[descriptionTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@" "]) 
    {
        return kCellHeight * 2.0;
    }
    // Cell isn't selected so return single height
    return  kCellHeight;
}
```

selectedIndexes is an object ofNSMutableDictonary which is declared in .h file
i have created tableview where it animates based upon description present in the cell or not .. while it animates , if i select a row the row size increases and when i tap on it once again the row size should go back to normal height , i am only able to do that when i select another row/cell , i want to cell to go back to normal height when i tap on the selected row .

Comment: One question: it's not entirely clear if you want user to be able to select more then one item at a time or only one? You implemented NSMutableArray - that leads to belive that more then one. But then you clear all selected indexes when user taps one...

Comment: the user has to select only one item at a time . the code which is there allows user to select only one item at a time .. its just that when the user touches say 1st item the cell increases . but when the user touches the same item the cell has to return to its normal height . i am not able to figure how to do it

Comment: I think there is some problem in with selectedIndexes array. you say only one (or none) cell can be selected at the time. Then insted of array use just NSIndexPath *selectedIndex (which can be nil if no cell is selected). Code would be more readable that way and easier to find a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code was just tested and it works. You will have to modify it for your needs but the basic behaviour should suit your needs.

Note that there is no need to call `beginUpdates/endUpdates`.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *lastSelectedCell;;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize lastSelectedCell = _lastSelectedCell;;

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil)  {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d %@",indexPath.row, ([indexPath compare:_lastSelectedCell] == NSOrderedSame)?@"S":@"-"];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"S: %d", indexPath.row);

    if (([indexPath compare:_lastSelectedCell] == NSOrderedSame)) {
        _lastSelectedCell = nil;
    } else {
        [self setLastSelectedCell: indexPath];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    return  ([indexPath compare:_lastSelectedCell] == NSOrderedSame)?80.0:40.0;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    _tableView = nil;
    _lastSelectedCell = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your sweet code, I'd like to use animation while expanding cell ,How could I achieve this ,Thanks in advanced

Comment: Hi! I did a quick test and it seems adding `[tableView beginUpdates];[tableView endUpdates];` before `[tableView reloadData];` adds animation effect. You would probably want to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` instead of simple `reloadData` since it results in much cleaner animation. You do have to pass it an array of rows you want to reaload though (final solution depends on desired functionality).